# how to display sub menu on horizontal css menu

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS Menu:

http://jsfiddle.net/73GrF/

but i cannot work out what css code i need for the hover:

```
#nav li a:hover
```

Answer (score 1):

trigger the hover on your `li` element. Don't forget to set your submenu position to absolute

```
#nav li:hover ul {
     display:block;   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/73GrF/4/ (edited fiddle with crude dropdown styling. ill leave the dressing up to you.)

Comment: how can i style it so the sub menu links display below each other

Comment: thats where the absolute positioning comes into play.. 1 sec, ill update the fiddle and answer.

Comment: You'll also have to make sure that you can mouseover the siblings.

Comment: i cannot select any of the items on the sub menu because they need to display directly under the parent link

Comment: adjust your placement with css. this is a helping forum not a do-it-for-me site.. research a bit.. http://bit.ly/1jztlYf

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/73GrF/5/ is what I came up with while McMastermind was at work.

The main thing I've done is taken the margins off, floated the menu headers, and made the submenus appear on hover

```
#nav>li {
    float:left

}
#nav li:hover ul {
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
}

#nav li a {
    margin:0;
}
```